# avoid Headset plugout stops AVAudioPlayer in iOS

Tags: iphone, xcode4.5

In my iPhone app I am using AVAudioPlayer to play the songs...But when I plug out or plugin the headset during song playing, It automatically stops the AVAudioPlayer... I need to run audio player even though these changes occur.. any ideas will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm facing same problem. I'm using audioRouteChangeListenerCallback, don't specifically stop/pause audio, and don't recall having this issue in older versions of iOS. I use AVAudioPlayer and AVAudioRecorder for playing and recording at same time. I previously ported just playback of streams to a streamer class that uses AudioQueue and audio plays fine with that when plugging and unplugging headphones repeatedly.

Comment: Weird, on the contrary...I'm using AVAudioPlayer too in my app, and try to find why the audio play is not paused when taking off the headphones, like airPod.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer.

Just we have to Import the followings

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>
```

and write this code

```
//Play the Event in Background
NSError *setCategoryErr = nil;
NSError *activationErr  = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: &setCategoryErr];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: &activationErr];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier newTaskId = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
newTaskId = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:NULL];
```

Now its continuously playing even I plugged in&out the Ear phone.

Comment: Could you also explain what this code does or changes? It's not really apparent...

Comment: didn't solve the problem for me. any other suggestions?

Comment: Not a very good help. Your code seems to be unrelated to your problem. Could you explain?

Answer (score 10):

First, you have to tell `AVAudioSession` the audio behaviour of your app. Apple name this the *audio session category*, an can be set by

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryErr];
```

For example, `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` :

> When using this category, your app audio continues with the Silent switch set to silent or when the screen locks. (The switch is called the Ring/Silent switch on iPhone.)
>
> This category normally prevents audio from other apps from mixing with your app's audio. To allow mixing for this category, use the kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers property.

Then, once the audio session set, the app will respond to some audio notifications, like `AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification` or `AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification`

To answer, the original question, `AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification` is called when the audio route has been changed (ex: headset plug-out/plug-in, but also bluetooth device turning off, ...). With a bit of code, we can find the route change reason. And, in our case, start the player again il the headset has been unplugged.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    NSError *setCategoryErr;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryErr];
    
    // Detects when the audio route changes (ex: jack unplugged)
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(audioHardwareRouteChanged:) name:AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification object:nil];
    // Don't forget to remove notification in dealloc method!!
}

- (void)audioHardwareRouteChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSInteger routeChangeReason = [notification.userInfo[AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey] integerValue];
    if (routeChangeReason == AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonOldDeviceUnavailable) {
        // if we're here, the player has been stopped, so play again!
        [self.player play];
    }
}
```

To conclude, also think about a user, in a boring meeting, who accidentaly plug-out his headset. He would not have this kind of behaviour, whose would make the device suddently scream in the room!

Comment: In swift: `NSNotification.Name.AVAudioSessionRouteChange`

Comment: [player play],i am geeting  this error No known class method for selector 'play'

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3**

Setup your player - play audio (even on silent mode) and silence other music / podcasts:

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
_ = try? audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: .duckOthers)
_ = try? audioSession.setActive(true)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(audioRouteChanged), name: .AVAudioSessionRouteChange, object: nil)
```

Route change observer (fix for unplugging headphones during playback):

```
func audioRouteChanged(note: Notification) {
  if let userInfo = note.userInfo {
    if let reason = userInfo[AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey] as? Int {
      if reason == AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason.oldDeviceUnavailable.rawValue {
        // headphones plugged out
        player.play()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Swift 2**

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
_ = try? audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, withOptions: .DuckOthers)
_ = try? audioSession.setActive(true)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(audioRouteChanged), name: AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

Route change observer:

```
func audioRouteChanged(note: NSNotification) {
  if let userInfo = note.userInfo {
    if let reason = userInfo[AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey] as? Int {
      if reason == AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason.OldDeviceUnavailable.rawValue {
        // headphones plugged out -> continue playback
        player.play()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Should be `rawValue` instead of `hashValue`?

Comment: @chengsam I can't test at the moment but the above worked when I needed it (as far as I know). If you end up testing it, please let us know if it's still valid.

Comment: I tested with Swift 5 and `rawValue` worked for me instead of `hashValue`, don't know if `hashValue` is working in Swift 3.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old post but i did some research about this. @Martin answer was correct and i am using NSNotificationCenter but i am using Swift3 so these are things you can get from notification.userInfo

```
case AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotificationKey
/* value is an NSNumber representing an AVAudioSessionInterruptionType */

case AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionsKey */
/* Only present for end interruption events.  Value is of type AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptions.*/

case AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey */
/* value is an NSNumber representing an AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason */
    case unknown
    case newDeviceAvailable
    case oldDeviceUnavailable
    case categoryChange
    case override 
    case wakeFromSleep
    case noSuitableRouteForCategory
    case routeConfigurationChange

case AVAudioSessionRouteChangePreviousRouteKey * */
/* value is AVAudioSessionRouteDescription * */
    case input
    case output

case AVAudioSessionSilenceSecondaryAudioHintTypeKey */
/* value is an NSNumber representing an AVAudioSessionSilenceSecondaryAudioHintType */
```

Here is method in swift3

```
func audioSessionRouteChange(notification: NSNotification) {

    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {

        print("Notification: AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey = \(userInfo[AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey])")
        print("Notification: AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionKey = \(userInfo[AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionKey])")
        print("Notification: AVAudioSessionSilenceSecondaryAudioHintTypeKey = \(userInfo[AVAudioSessionSilenceSecondaryAudioHintTypeKey])")

        if let reason = userInfo[AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey] as? Int {

            print("Notification: AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonOldDeviceUnavailable")

            if reason == AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason.oldDeviceUnavailable.hashValue {

                print("Notification: Headphones out")
            }

            if reason == AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason.newDeviceAvailable.hashValue {

                print("Notification: Headphones in")
            }
        }

        if let description = userInfo[AVAudioSessionRouteChangePreviousRouteKey] as? AVAudioSessionRouteDescription {

            // here you can check previous input and output 
            // po description.outputs[0].portType == AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInSpeaker

            print("Notification: AVAudioSessionRouteChangePreviousRouteKey Inputs: \(description.inputs)")
            print("Notification: AVAudioSessionRouteChangePreviousRouteKey Outputs: \(description.outputs)")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Martin is almost right except when we get `AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification` notification, the audio may still play, you must check player's `rate` property. If it is zero, play it, otherwise you should observe `rate`, when it change to zero, play it. Check the [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/responding_to_audio_session_route_changes?language=objc)

Another note is that `AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification` is posted on a background thread (not main thread), you should dispatch it to the main thread if needed.

Answer (score 1):

thanks to @budidino Swift 5 and above

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
_ = try? audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback, options: .duckOthers)
 _ = try? audioSession.setActive(true)
            
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(audioRouteChanged), name: AVAudioSession.routeChangeNotification, object: nil)


@objc func audioRouteChanged(note: Notification) {
      if let userInfo = note.userInfo {
        if let reason = userInfo[AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey] as? Int {
            if reason == AVAudioSession.RouteChangeReason.oldDeviceUnavailable.rawValue {
            // headphones plugged out
            self.avPlayer?.play()
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best tutorial dealing this issue: (working well also on iOS7)

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Detecting_when_an_iPhone_Headphone_or_Docking_Connector_is_Unplugged_(iOS_4)